# How stable is setting the Visible property of non-automatic columns in a WinForms DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Before starting to hunt down my Visible False/True issue:

> How stable is setting the Visible property of non-automatic columns in
>   a WinForms DataGridView?

I've had had enough issues with strange artefacts in WinForms (for instance after all the years of their existing, fiddling around with FlowLayoutPanel and TableLayoutPanel at design time still gets the Visual Studio designer upset, changing the `ForeColor` on a `TextBox` doesn't always work, etc) so I am used to question the framework.

In my specific case, I set the Visible property of the two last columns on a DataGridView (all columns at design time, bound data is a collection of in memory objects) both in a `backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted` and in a `myCheckBox_CheckedChanged` event.

Observations:

1. in the `backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted`, setting `Visible = False` hides the column, but later setting `Visible = True` doesn't reveal it
2. in the `myCheckBox_CheckedChanged`, setting `Visible = myCheckBox.Checked` has no effect at all (does not hide or reveal)

Before digging deeply into this, and getting an [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) out: how stable should this normally be?

Answer (score 1):

My personal experience with this is that visibility of controls like bound `DataGridView`s can be temperamental. I would use the `Update()` method, and this may resolve the visibility issue. Failing that an `this.Update()` on the form and eventually a full form refresh using `this.Refresh()`.

As far as the `CheckBox`s visibility goes if the `CheckBox` is bound to some underlying data source, this could prevent such an update. However, doing

```
private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkBox.Visible = checkBox.Checked;
}
```

should be fine. I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm going to dig some deeper. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Did you have any luck using `Update()/Refresh()`?

Comment: Not yet. I'm in the midst of another project right now.